# How to list bluetooth devices from command line

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, bluetooth

I have to list all available bluetooth devices from command line. I tried to google it, but got only results like "how to turn on bluetooth from terminal".

Simply: bluetooth scan

Thanks for help in  advance.

Comment: by available you mean paired ? or do you mean Bluetooth scan ?

Comment: would this work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11682731/2241562

Comment: Bluetooth scan.

Comment: this q/a seems a bit confusing - does `bluetooth scan` list all nearby devices that are discoverable or does the answer below by njboot return that?

Answer (score 9):

Simply typing in:

```
blued

bluetoothd (Mojave or newer)
```

Will return a list of paired devices according to to the link key. I don't know how to have it exit cleanly, so to return to the prompt you will need to press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: would you use the same command for devices scan (not paired)

Comment: @Buscar웃 Honestly not sure. When I run it, it shows a few other key values of other devices I own which aren't linked -but bluetooth enabled. It's hard to identify the devices themselves based on the output though - looks almost like MAC addresses (though its not). Thanks for pointing out that distinction.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm not sure if the additional listings were previously connected devices though, or ones resulting from an active scan.

Comment: I tried yours and it did show previously paired devices on my mac (that are currently not connected). I do not think it does the active scan for all surrounding BT devices.

Comment: @Buscar웃 the other alternative is it shows available devices which aren't paired but which *were previously* and are currently available (and thus, have already established a link key with the MBP). I agree though - I don't believe this shows a full scan of all available devices (that being - including those which weren't previously paired).

Comment: This is `bluetoothd` on Mojave.

Comment: @njboot I wish there was a way to do this

Answer (score 4):

`blueutil --inquiry [T]`

This will list all the devices within range. You can optionally specify a time duration in seconds.

blueutil lives on [GitHub](https://github.com/toy/blueutil) and you can install it through Homebrew (`brew install blueutil`). It's also available through [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/blueutil/) (`sudo port install blueutil`